# Show that $(p,X)/(pℤ[X])$ isomorph to $(X)$

Tags: ring-theory

Let $p$ prime. Let $(p,X)$ the ideal generated by $p$ and $X$ of the ring $ℤ[X]$.

> Show that $(p,X)/(pℤ[X])$ isomorph to $(X)$ where $(X)=X ℤ_p[X]$

I think I need to use that if $f:R → R'$ a ringhomomorphism, then $R/\ker(f)$ isomorh to $f(R)$. But I don't see which $f$ I need to chose, to make this true.

Comment: Consider the natural map $\mathbb{Z}[X] \mapsto \mathbb{Z}_p[X]$ which sends the coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ to their images in $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Okay so you have $f:ℤ[X]→ℤ_p[X] :\sum a_i X^i ↦ \sum \bar{a_i} X^i$. Then $\ker(f) = pℤ[X]$ and $f[(p,X)]$ is polynomials of the form $a_iX$ with $a_i \in ℤ_p$ right ? Do you mean something like this ?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I feel like I don't really use the theorem as I take $f(X)$ where $X$ is a subset of the domain $R$

Answer (score 2):

I customarily don't think of ideals as forming rings, because for me rings have identities. So I wouldn't apply the idea of the OP. Instead, I think of the claim as being more about modules (in this case, over the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$).

There is a useful result in module theory (or homological algebra if you like) called the $3 \times 3$ lemma that is relevant here. (Arguably it is overkill here, but it is worth knowing about so I'll put it down.) It says that in a commutative diagram like

$$\begin{matrix}
 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & \\
 & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \\ 
0 & \to & p\mathbb{Z}[x] & \to & (p, x) & \to & x\mathbb{Z}_p[x] & \to & 0 \\
 & & 1 \downarrow & & i \downarrow & & i \downarrow & & \\ 
0 & \to & p\mathbb{Z}[x] & \stackrel{i}{\to} & \mathbb{Z}[x] & \to & \mathbb{Z}_p[x] & \to & 0 \\
 & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \\ 
0 & \to & 0 & \to & \mathbb{Z}_p & \stackrel{1}{\to} & \mathbb{Z}_p & \to & 0 \\ 
 & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \\ 
 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 
\end{matrix} 
$$

in which all columns are exact, if the bottom two of the three rows are exact, then so is the top (and, if the top two rows are exact, so is the bottom). See [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/3x3+lemma) in the nLab, or see any text on homological algebra, e.g., the one by Hilton and Stammbach. Clearly in our situation here, the three columns and the bottom two rows are short exact sequences, so we get the claim.